# which datasource doesn't supports caching in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datasource, sqldatasource

we have different data sources like

- sqldataource
- objectdatasource
- linqdatasource
- xmldatasource

Out of which doesn't supports caching

Answer (score 1):

All of them support caching. The LinqDataSource has the concept of "object tracking" (which is turned on by default) that enables caching of data in order to determined if objects change and it also enables deferred query execution.